# Twitter Bootstrap's 3 default theme is not working with IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, initializr

I've downloaded latest initializer: http://www.initializr.com/ to start a new project. As I have to support IE8 I quickly run through tests. And it turned out that when default theme is included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

and I try to open sub-menu of **Dropdown** navigation menu, I see nothing:
[(Screenshot full size)](http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2270-250.html)

[image]

Actually you can see that dropdown menu is opening, but it's totally transparent. Is it common issue? Does it mean I have to give up on using default Bootstrap's theme?

Comment: I develop for IE8 (corporate requirement) and just deployed a BS3-based site last week, and it uses the dropdowns in the menu, too.  Are you sure you've got the "html5shiv.js" and "respond.min.js" scripts loading correctly.  If you're missing them, here's a direct link to them from the BS3 assets distro... [GitHugb:bootstrap/assets/js/](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/assets/js).  I don't know if that helps or not, as I can't tell what's loading from just the screenshot.

Comment: Responsive layout works. Modernizer is loading correctly too. There's only a problem with styles. Are you sure you're using a theme from bootstrap-theme.css ?

Comment: I have the exact same issue with bootstrap-theme.min.css and IE8.

Comment: This is a known issue of bootstrap-theme.css: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10257

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same Issue and removed the below line inside the class navbar-default of the theme CSS:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#fff8f8f8', GradientType=0);
```